# How do you view data contained inside hidden directories with QGIS browser?

Tags: qgis, windows, qgis-browser

I am attempting to browse data in a hidden directory, but the QGIS Browser tree view doesn't show in hidden folders? I know, I know...it's hidden. But is there a command-line switch to override this behavior? The folder in question is APPDATA, so I don't want to make it visible.

Comment: Good reason to keep it hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: No. Not currently.  The browser model doesn't use the `QDir.Hidden` flags to show hidden files.

Can it be added to show them? Yep. Open a ticket on hub.qgis.org, assign it to me, and we can go from there.

Comment: I worked around by creating a visible junction to the directory under APPDATA that I wanted.  But it was all for naught, because the data in question was a file geodatabase and I didn't realize those weren't supported in browser yet (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5814).